# Installation VT220 terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, serial-port

I want to know how to connect a Digital VT220 terminal to PC-Linux with Ubuntu 12.04 using a serial-USB device.

At the moment I did next steps:

1. `sudo vi ttyS1.conf`  (at /etc/init)

   ```
   # ttyS1 - getty
   start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] and (
               not-container or
               container CONTAINER=lxc or
               container CONTAINER=lxc-libvirt)
   stop on runlevel [!2345]
   respawn
   exec /sbin/getty -8 19200 ttyS1
   ```
2. `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS1 19200 cs8 crtscts -echo`

Comment: Anyway......... lol... so you told us what you *tried*, but not what *output* you got. So that's pretty useless. Can you tell us what messages you got when you ran that `stty` command? Did anything show up in `dmesg`? Does anything print to the terminal? Throw us a bone, here...

Comment: This is a very *superuser* thing to be doing!

Comment: @allquixotic: In `dmesg` you should see only messages related to the serial port not to the connected terminal.

Answer (score 0):

On most systems I've had USB-to-RS232 adapters on, the device name shows up as `/dev/ttyUSB0` not `/dev/ttyS0`.  `/dev/ttyS0` refers to the first motherboard serial port, if one is there.  Look in your `/dev` directory to be sure.

Please note that if you connect more than one USB-to-RS232 serial adapter to your system, the filename may change (i.e. it may be `/dev/ttyUSB1` the next time you connect it or reboot) so if you want it persistent look into modifying the appropriate `udev` rules.